# Javascript функция сворачивания многомерного массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, клонирование

Я использую в коде функцию, которая многомерный массив схлопывает до одного уровня. Я начал использовать Spread(троеточие) для клонирования объектов и конкатенации, но мимнификатор который я использую, не работает с этого Spread, и боюсь некотрые браузеры пока не смогут с этим работать. В общем и я попытался это оптимизировать, но у меня ничего не вышло.

Изначальный код(без минификации и в моем "самом последнем хроме" все работает):

```
obj.flatten = function(arr){
    var arrCopy = obj.copyObject(arr);
    var flat = [].concat(...arrCopy);//<-- хочу заменить это
    return flat.some(Array.isArray) ? obj.flatten(flat) : flat;
};//flatten
```

Пробовал например сделать вот так:

```
obj.flatten = function(arr){
    var arrCopy = obj.copyObject(arr);
    var flat = [].concat([arrCopy]);//я думал, что это сработает...
    return flat.some(Array.isArray) ? obj.flatten(flat) : flat;
};//flatten
```

....не сработало:

```
utils.js?f=1499803982027:19 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at Object.obj.copyObject (utils.js?f=1499803982027:19)
    at Object.obj.flatten (utils.js?f=1499803982027:44)
    at Object.obj.flatten (utils.js?f=1499803982027:49)
    at Object.obj.flatten (utils.js?f=1499803982027:49)
    at Object.obj.flatten (utils.js?f=1499803982027:49)
    at Object.obj.flatten (utils.js?f=1499803982027:49)
    at Object.obj.flatten (utils.js?f=1499803982027:49)
    at Object.obj.flatten (utils.js?f=1499803982027:49)
    at Object.obj.flatten (utils.js?f=1499803982027:49)
```

copyObject:

```
obj.copyObject = function(arr){
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
};//copyObject
```

Подскажите пожалуйста чем заменить ...Spread?

**UPD.**
пример вызова:

```
console.log(tmp);
arr = utils.flatten(tmp);
```

вывод console.log(tmp):
[image: вывод console.log(tmp)]

Comment: добавь пример как ты вызываешь свою функцию

Comment: для массива _arrCopy_ нет разницы вызываешь ты `[].concat(...arrCopy)` или `[].concat(arrCopy)` результат будет одинаковым

Comment: хм... интересно. я тоже заметил на простых примерах, что разницы нет.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос пример вызова и лог данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
obj.flatten = function(arr){
    var arrCopy = obj.copyObject(arr);
    var flat = [].concat.apply([], arrCopy);
    return flat.some(Array.isArray) ? obj.flatten(flat) : flat;
};//flatten
```

Comment: получил ошибку:  
utils.js?f=1499804874405:49 Uncaught TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object

Comment: @silksofthesoul, проблема не в этом, все работает -
 https://jsfiddle.net/xrtydaka/

Comment: Да вы правы. О чудо, кажется я понял в чем дело. Крашится тогда когда в предложенном вам варианте попадает не массив, а строка.

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста в ваш пример проверку на тип, и условие "если это строка", то строку нужно разсплитовать на массив. и после этого запихнуть в .apply([],arrCopy) ...И я приму ваш ответ.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, ваш вариант очень  помог! (flat.some(Arr...  --- более не нужен тогда!)

Answer (score 2):

В итоге благодаря помощи @Hekumok и подсказкам @Mikhail M функция приобрела вид:

```
obj.flatten = function(arr){
    if(typeof arr =="string"){
        arr = arr.split("");
    }
    return [].concat.apply([], arr);
};//flatten
```

потребность в

```
flat.some(Array.isArray) ? obj.flatten(flat) : flat;
```

-- отпала, так как

```
[].concat.apply([], arr);
```

сворачивает любую вложенность массива до одного уровня(до ie9 вроде даже работает).

Выяснилось, что Spread строку превращает в массив.

Answer (score 1):

копирование на каждом шаге рекурсии не нужно

```js
var myArr = [1, 'a', function() {} , [2,[3,4, 5,6]], 7];

var utils = {};

utils.flatten = function(arr) {
    var concatenated = [].concat.apply([], arr);
    return concatenated.some(Array.isArray) ? utils.flatten(concatenated) : concatenated;
}

console.log('flattened:', utils.flatten(myArr));
console.log('original:', myArr);
```

Comment: тут и apply не нужен

Comment: @Grundy https://jsfiddle.net/srjqwwu4/

Comment: ...Соглашусь с вами... Эта подстраховка от нечаянного изменения. //// Убрал копирование. вроде ничего не слетело.

Comment: нужно конечно some(Array.isArray)... - это условие завершения рекурсии. apply - это просто хак из ES5

Comment: @MikhailM Да мне рекурсия не нужна. Это я когда то нагуглил способ сворачивать массивы и его оставил. решение с apply() --прекрасно с этим справляется. ...по крайней мере ничего не отвалилось вроде :-)